# Excel VBA get table range on unactive worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I cannot figure out why this statement does not work.

```
Rng = Worksheets(sheetName).ListObjects(table).Range.Select
```

I have a sheet "sheetX" with a button that invokes a subprocess "export_json" in the global workspace "Thisworkbook". I want the subprocess in "Thisworkbook" to reference a table range on "sheetX" at "A2" but it gives an error "Application-defined or Object-defined error". I do not want to use Application.Goto

Why is that? I'm overlooking something basic

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    sheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    Call ThisWorkbook.export_json(sheet)
End Sub

Public Sub export_json(sheetName)
    table = ThisWorkbook.get_table(Worksheets(sheetName).Range("A2"))
    Rng = Worksheets(sheetName).ListObjects(table).Range.Select
    Rng = Selection.Address
```

table is of type string and sheet is the correct sheet name of type string so that is not the problem.

Comment: do not use `select` ... that has been repeated so many times here  .... `Rng = Worksheets(sheetName).ListObjects(table).Range.Address`

Comment: you do not need to know the table name ... this works  `Rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Range("A2").ListObject.Range.Address`

Answer (score 0):

Your syntaxing looks a little off, when your trying declare `Rng` in the function `export_json()` you should pass it as a string.

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim sheetX As String
    sheetX = ActiveSheet.Name
    Call export_json("sheetX")

End Sub

Private Function export_json(sheetName As String)

    table = ThisWorkbook.get_table(Worksheets(sheetName).Range("A2"))
    Worksheets(sheetName).ListObjects(table).Range.Select

End Function
```

Comment: No unfortunately that didn't work. I've tried adding as String in the parameter"

Comment: @jsotola He may need the selection for user purposes, that's reason why I left it there... Just trying to fix his code; other wise yes, you're completely right, `.select` is yucky!

Comment: @Maldred, please edit your code in some way, add a space or something, so that i can remove my downvote (unable to remove until answer is edited) ... of course if he needs the selection for something else then remove the  `Rng =` from the `rng = worksheets ...` line and make it a select command only

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, there's no need to use `Select`.

Also, it is not clear to me why you keep the code of your `Function` in `ThisWorkbook` module, instead of a regular module.

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim TableRangeString As String

    TableRangeString = ThisWorkbook.export_json(ActiveSheet.Name)

    ' for debug
    MsgBox TableRangeString

End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function export_json(sheetName) As String
    ' use the function to return the Range.Address by changing it to return a String

    Dim Rng As Range

    Set Rng = Worksheets(sheetName).Range("A2").ListObject.Range
    export_json = Rng.Address

End Function
```